# how to extract this string from python

Tags: python, regex, string

my string is something like this:

```
blah, blah1, blah2 / foo, foo2, foo3
```

I want to extract "blah, blah1, blah2"
and "foo, foo2, foo3"

How can I do it in Python?

For example: 
Original string is `s = blah, blah1, blah2 / foo, foo2, foo3.`
After extracting:

str1 = "blah, blah1, blah2"
str2 = "foo, foo2, foo3"

Comment: Read: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split

Answer (score 2):

Use the [str.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
text.split(' / ')
```

---

```
In [1]: text = 'blah, blah1, blah2 / foo, foo2, foo3'

In [2]: text.split(' / ')
Out[2]: ['blah, blah1, blah2', 'foo, foo2, foo3']
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `split`, something like this:

```
s="blah, blah1, blah2 / foo, foo2, foo3"
s.split("/")
```

yields:

```
['blah, blah1, blah2 ', ' foo, foo2, foo3']
```